# median of selected rows dependent on other columns values

Tags: r, median

I have the following data frame (here just a tiny part from a big one)

```
ID= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
week = c(1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2)
X = c(3.3,4.23,5.6,12,3.1,4.3,5.9,6.1,5.3)
Y = c(1.3,2.4,6.8,5.5,4.3,3,6.6,2.6,5.7)
TS_DF = data.frame(ID,week,X,Y)
```

I would like to calculated the median of X and Y separately for each `ID` and `week` so that the results reads like this

```
ID    week  X     Y     weekMedX    weekMedY
1     1     3.3   1.3   3.765       1.85
1     1     4.23  2.4   3.765       1.85
1     2     5.6   6.8   5.6         6.8
2     1     12    5.5   7.55        4.9
2     1     3.1   4.3   7.55        4.9
2     2     4.3   3     5.1         4.8
2     2     5.9   6.6   5.1         4.8
3     1     6.1   2.6   6.1         2.6
3     2     5.3   5.7   5.3         5.7
```

Based on [this discusssion](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-average-mean-variables-in-r-based-on-the-level-of-another-variable-and-save-this-as-a-new-variable/8764/7) I came up with the following code

```
b = TS_DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(median = median(X))
```

but I get wrong results

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
week median
<dbl>  <dbl>
1     1   4.23
2     2   5.45
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated. M

Comment: Maybe try `group_by(ID, week)` instead of two separate groupings...

Comment: Adding a new group_by() statement will overwrite any previous groupings.

Comment: add `week` in your grouping variable (togetehr with `ID`) and use `mutate` instead of `summarise`

Comment: Thank you all, it works! One more question: how do I pipe it back and exted the original TS_DF with columns with the medians?

Comment: using 'mutate' is answering my question of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commentators suggested, this should work:

```
b = TS_DF %>%
  group_by(ID, week)  %>%
  mutate(median_X = median(X), median_Y = median(Y))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you went the summarise route, you can use a join to bring all the data together.

```
median_df = TS_DF %>%
  group_by(ID, week) %>%
  summarise(median = median(X))

final_df <- left_join(TS_DF, median_df, by = c('ID', 'week'))
```

This should give you the original dataframe plus the calculated medians.

Answer (score 1):

As some commenters have already mentioned:

Use only one group_by() expression:

```
library(dplyr)
TS_DF %>% 
  group_by(ID, week) %>% 
  summarise(median_X = median(X),
            median_Y = median(Y))
```

Otherwise only the last group_by() is used. See also the output of

```
TS_DF %>%
  group_by(ID, week)
```

A tibble: 9 x 4
Groups:   ID, week [6]

versus the output of:

```
TS_DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  group_by(week)
```

A tibble: 9 x 4
Groups:   week [2]